# How to fix "list indices must be integers or slices" error

Tags: python, list, shelve

I'm making a program that should save your ip address to a list in a separate file using shelve. Each time it is opened it should put the the ip address in list "pubipcount" in list "pubiplist". When I go to add a new ip I get an error that I don't understand.

I've only ran the code bit by bit to find the part that is broken, and I've taken the liberty of narrowing it down to only the information you need to help me. I've already looked online for a possible answer but I haven't found anything helpful to me.

```
import shelve
import socket
import urllib.request

save = shelve.open('ip_whitelist', writeback=True)

hostname = socket.gethostname()
PubIP = urllib.request.urlopen('https://ident.me').read().decode('utf8')
LocIP = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)

save['pubipcount'] = 0
save['pubiplist'] = []

save['pubipcount'] = save['pubipcount'] + 1
save['pubiplist']['pubipcount'] = PubIP
```

This is the exact error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\brenn\Desktop\IP\ip.py", line 27, in <module>
    save['pubiplist']['pubipcount'] = PubIP
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `['pubipcount']`. In the context it is just a string. I believe you want:

```
save['pubiplist'][save['pubipcount']] = PubIP
```

This way you are referring to the value in `save['pubipcount']` instead of the string `'pubipcount'` as the index.

Edit:
This will likely result in an IndexError, so using `append()` is better

```
save['pubiplist'].append(PubIP)
```

Comment: This will likely throw `IndexError: list assignment index out of range` error. Shall use `save['pubiplist'].append(PubIP)` instead

Answer (score 1):

if you use a `list` the index must be integers such as `save['pubiplist'][0]`

if you want a `str` as key, you can use a `dict` instead, change `save['pubiplist'] = []` to `save['pubiplist'] = {}`

---

for your situation, I suggest you to use `PubIP` as key, and count `PubIP` separately:

```
from collections import defaultdict
# do this only once
save['pubiplist'] = defaultdict(int)

# recieve IP repeately

# update IP and count each time
save['pubiplist'][PubIP] += 1
```

Comment: I think this will be really inefficient as it scales. The whole dictionary will have to be read and written on each update. It is better to save a key for each IP

Comment: yeah, initialization should be done only one time. @bpaul

Comment: I'm looking to keep pubipcount saved in a separate file so I can keep it on a server and no matter who uses it the number will be the same.

Answer (score 1):

Shelve allows you use strings as keys but you can't use them as sub-indexes.

The quickest fix would be to interpolate the count into the key:

```
save[f'pubiplist-{pubipcount}'] = PubIP
```

Comment: I'm looking to keep pubipcount saved in a separate file so I can keep it on a server and no matter who uses it the number will be the same.